# App de tradução Text to Speech - Android

Tags: java, android, tradução

Olá, sou iniciante em android e gostaria de fazer um tradutor simples, onde o usuário escreva qualquer coisa e clique no botão com a língua desejada para traduzir em voz alta, como seria o algorítimo de tradução para outras línguas ? Segue o meu código

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        edt_texto =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_texto);
        btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        t2s = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                t2s.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fala = edt_texto.getText().toString();

                t2s.speak(fala,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: TextToSpeech não traduz. Ele apenas faz o discurso sintetizado do texto.

Answer (score 2):

Já está a utilizar outras línguas.

Ao usar:

```
t2s.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
```

Está a utilizar a linguagem seleccionada no dispositivo.

Pode, no entanto, definir uma linguagem diferente com:

```
t2s.setLanguage( new Locale("en", "US"));
```

ou

```
t2s.setLanguage( Locale.JAPAN );
```

ou ainda:

```
t2s.setLanguage( Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US") );
```

Comment: TextToSpeech não traduz. Ele apenas faz o discurso sintetizado do texto.

Comment: Peço desculpa, não tinha compreendido.
Também andei à procura de uma biblioteca de tradução para java mas, infelizmente, não encontrei nenhuma. A única alternativa será uma API de tradução, mas o utilizador terá que estar online para a utilizar.